# replace sqlite3 database table with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

My sqlite3 database look like the following:

```
id     name
1      apple
2      orange
3      pear
4      bananna
```

Then I query each element from the database into a pandas dataframe.

After that I merge the dataframe with a list.

After that I sort the database element by the list.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3', isolation_level=None, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from name', conn)

#I am getting the list .....

df["color"] = color #color is a list
df.sort_values(by=['color'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

How could I replace the original sqlite3 table with the sorted dataframe? I do not want to add the color column to the sqlite3 table.

Comment: `df.sort_values("color",ignore_index=True).drop("color",axis=1).to_sql("name",conn,if_exists='replace')`?

Comment: Why do you think order matters in database?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh there is other purpose of sorting the database

Comment: @not_speshal I am using `DB Browser for SQLite` so I can see the database. ˛`Indices` is appeard. Now there is 4 column in the table. level_0 (0,1,2,3,4...) index (6,7,9...) id (7,8,10,3...) and the name. Name column is in the good order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer:

```
db.sort_values(by=['color'], ascending=True).drop('color',axis=1).to_sql("name",conn,if_exists='replace',index=False, index_label="id")
```